# Alterar Dados com Mysql no PHP buscando o id a partir da tela de login

Tags: php

```html
TELA DE LOGIN  

<?php

    $nome_usuario=$_POST["nome_usuario"];
    $senha=$_POST["Senha"];
    $Status=$_POST["Status"];

    $conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Erro durante a conexão do banco de dados");
    mysql_select_db("prestadora",$conexao);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $conexao);
    mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $conexao);
    $verifica="select Nome_Usuario,Senha from cliente where Nome_Usuario = '$nome_usuario' and Senha = '$senha'";
    $result=mysql_query($verifica,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível executa o Login.");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
  
    mysql_close($conexao);


    if($count == 1){

        echo"<fieldset id='form_field'><legend id='form_legend'>Login</legend><p>Bem Vindo !!!</p></fieldset>";
        echo '<meta HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="2; URL=../MenuCliente.html">';


    }else{


        echo"<fieldset id='form_field'><legend id='form_legend'>Login</legend><p>Usuario e senha não conferem</p></fieldset>";
    }

    ?>


TELA DE ALTERAR CADASTRO

  <?php
$nome_usuario=$_POST["nome_usuario"];
$senha=$_POST["senha"];
$nome=$_POST["nome"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$RG=$_POST["RG"];
$CPF=$_POST["CPF"];
$CEP=$_POST["CEP"];
$sexo=$_POST["sexo"];
$endereco=$_POST["end"];
$bairro=$_POST["bairro"];
$cidade=$_POST["cidade"];
$estado=$_POST["estado"];
$telefone=$_POST["tel"];
$celular=$_POST["cel"];



$conexao = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","root") or die("Erro durante a conexão do banco de dados");
mysql_select_db("prestadora",$conexao);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $conexao);
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8', $conexao);
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8', $conexao);
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8', $conexao);
$atualiza= "update cliente set Nome ='$nome',Sexo ='$sexo',RG ='$RG',CEP ='$CEP',CPF ='$CPF',Estado ='$estado',Cidade ='$cidade',Bairro ='$bairro',Endereco ='$endereco',TEL ='$telefone',CEl ='$celular',Email ='$email',Nome_Usuario ='$nome_usuario',Senha ='$senha' " ;
mysql_query($atualiza,$conexao) or die ("Não foi possível executar a atualização.");
mysql_close($conexao);



echo"<fieldset id='form_field'><legend id='form_legend'>Dados do Usuario</legend>
  $nome_usuario<br/>$senha<br/>$nome<br/>$email<br/>$sexo<br/>$RG<br/>$CPF<br/>$CEP<br/>$endereco<br/>$bairro<br/>
$cidade<br/>$estado<br/>$telefone<br/>$celular<br/>
</fieldset>";



?>
```

Quero pegar o id que eu usei na tela de login para alterar os dados de um cliente. Mas estou sem ideias de como fazer isso.

Comment: $_SESSION['id'] = $count['id'];

Answer (score 0):

Obtendo o resultado da consulta:

```
 $count=mysqli_query($conexao, $result);
```

então você pode verificar se o login e senha possuem dados, se possuir, você recupera o valor

```
 session_start();
if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($conexao, $count)){
   $_SESSION['id'] = $count['id'];
   $id = $_SESSION['id'];

}
```

Então com o código recuperado você faz a sua alteração. Não recomento usar essa prática que está usando, porque fica muito inseguro, recomendo PDO

```
$login="update cliente set Nome_Usuario = '$nome_usuario',Senha = '$senha',Status='$Status' WHERE id =  $id ";
```

Aí na outra pagina você chama o $id que você recuperou

```
session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

Comment: Explique melhor a sua resposta para que o usuário que perguntou entenda o que te motivou a fazer desta forma.

Comment: Bom, o que eu queria mesmo é fazer a verificação e transportar a ID do usuario que ativou o login para outra pagina php de alterar cadastro

Comment: ah se for assim, você armazena numa sessão mesmo, alterei a resposta para ver se é isso mesmo

Comment: Warning: mysql_result() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Prestadora de Servicos\_php\login.php on line 51
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Prestadora de Servicos\_php\login.php on line 57

Comment: é porque atualmente é mysqli e geralmente ele espera a conexão e sua consulta, dei uma alterada

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_result() in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Prestadora de Servicos\_php\login.php on line 51

Comment: tente assim: $count=mysqli_query($conexao, $result);

Comment: Não há necessidade de armazenar id em sessão. Uma vez feito o login ele pode pegar o id e jogar direto num formulário `type=hidden`, já que a intenção é levar o usuário direto para a edição do perfil. Ele pode usar os métodos do HTTP, no caso, POST. `ID`, se for a chave-primária serve mais pra indexação no banco de dados, não seria uma boa ideia armazenar numa sessão.

Comment: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Prestadora de Servicos\_php\login.php on line 51
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\Prestadora de Servicos\_php\login.php on line 57

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.query.php

Comment: Mas não é só para paginar de alterar e sim de consultar e excluir.O login vai ter levar para um menu de seleções de opções e de lá vai para a de alterar.

Answer (score -1):

Quando efetuar o login, guarde em uma `$_SESSION['user_id']`.